# Как запускать (.ppt) методом поиска файла?

Tags: c#

Как через "button" запустить презентацию без прописывания пути, а методом поиска файла?

Знаю как через путь но если запущу программу на другом ПК то нужно будет заново прописывать путь, а это усложняет работу с программой.

```
Application ppApp = new Application();
ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;

Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;

_Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(
    @"C:\Users\Yarovou\Desktop\Laika.ppt",
    MsoTriState.msoFalse, 
    MsoTriState.msoFalse,
    MsoTriState.msoTrue
    );
```

Comment: Что значит "методом поиска"? Поиска чего?

Comment: поиска файла "lalka.ppt"

Comment: "Поиска файла" или "выбора файла"? Вы знаете, что этот файл есть на одном из дисков и его нужно найти - или хотите, чтобы пользователь сам указал путь к файлу?

Comment: Чтобы при запуске был запущен именно этот файл "lalka.ppt" без прописывания пути.Например вы запускаете мой проект со своего ПК,нажимаете на кнопку и чтобы вам автоматически открывался этот файл "lalka.ppt".

Comment: @Karkas А Ваш проект, это что? Какая-то программа, так? А где будет лежать lalka.ppt? Это распространяется вместе с Вашей программой или должно быть у юзера на компьютере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте свой файл в проект как Embedded Resource.
При запуске (или по кнопке, или когда надо) читайте через `Properties.Resources.<имя ресурса>` в виде массива байт, сливайте его во временный файл и этот файл открывайте.
Примерно как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26784348/2856962